# Pointing to different Pythons in my Pycharm and CLI

Tags: python, pointers, version-control, pycharm, dependencies

I'm running into an error where PyCharm is pointing to one python, and my config is set up to a different python.

The error I get is:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that matches python

When I type "which python" in my cli (within Pycharm of my project dir) I get:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/gunteh/bin/python

Looking at where it's set in Pycharm, I get:
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/gunteh/bin/python3.7

How can I get Pycharm to point to the same Python root directory, and avoid issues like below that force me to reinstall Pipfile and lock dependencies?

[Invalid error on Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZCV1.png)

Comment: Do you use pipenv?

Comment: Yes, Im using pipenv

Comment: Then choose base interpreter to be used in pipenv creation and click OK/Create on the page you've attached